# Using an @ symbol in strings.xml

Tags: android

How would one use an @ symbol inside a string in strings.xml?

```
<string name="twitter">@npike</string>
```

The XML editor gets rather angry:

```
error: Error: No resource type specified (at 'twitter' with value '@npike').
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use this instead :

```
<string name="twitter">\@npike</string>
```

Comment: This works on device, but the graphical interface doesn't like it.

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest use unicode like \u0040 instead of '@' symbol. XML processing doesn't like special symbols. Here is list of special characters and it's unicode values[Special characters and unicode values](http://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php?block=0)

Answer (score 2):

Try escaping it with a backslash "\@". That works for quotes. You can't use XML entities in strings.xml, otherwise I would recommend that.